# Checking whether two lists contain the same elements

Tags: sorting, complexity, fortran

I have two lists of numbers:

$$\{i_1, i_2, i_3,i_4\}$$ and $$\{j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4\}$$

The problem I want to solve is: Inside a loop, if the following two conditions are satisfied, then it will do something I want, otherwise it just cycle the loop. The conditions are:

1. Both lists contain four different numbers;
2. If ignoring the ordering, in other words, we view these two lists as two set, then they are the same.

I want to find a very fast way to get the answer to the problem. I have very slow Fortran code as follows:

```
if (i2==i1) cycle
if (i3==i1) cycle
if (i3==i2) cycle
if (i4==i1) cycle
if (i4==i2) cycle
if (i4==i3) cycle

if (j2==j1) cycle
if (j3==j1) cycle
if (j3==j2) cycle
if (j4==j1) cycle
if (j4==j2) cycle
if (j4==j3) cycle 
q1=0
q2=0
q3=0
q4=0
if (i1==j1)q1=1
if (i1==j2)q1=2
if (i1==j3)q1=3
if (i1==j4)q1=4
if (i2==j1)q2=1
if (i2==j2)q2=2
if (i2==j3)q2=3
if (i2==j4)q2=4
if (i3==j1)q3=1
if (i3==j2)q3=2
if (i3==j3)q3=3
if (i3==j4)q3=4
if (i4==j1)q4=1
if (i4==j2)q4=2
if (i4==j3)q4=3
if (i4==j4)q4=4

if (q1*q2*q3*q4==24)then
 Something I want to do
endif
```

I think to find a good program, the following should also be considered as well as cutting down the number of instructions:

1. The probability to have four different numbers in both lists are about 
   1/10;
2. The probability to have for these two lists containing two same set
   of numbers are very small, about 10^(-11);
3. I really have to do many loops.

Could someone help me out? I think a good idea can really boost the code.

Comment: What are the ranges of the loops? Are those if statements at the inner-most loop, or are they located at the top level of the loop(s)?

Comment: "_The probability to have four different numbers in both lists are about 1/10_" This is a lottery?

Comment: Hi @KyleKanos, thanks for asking, I modify the code in the question, hope it is clear this time.

Comment: @curiousguy, I am doing some extensive Monte Carlo simulation for a very rare event in clusters and the situation is very challenging.

Comment: @xjtan I don't understand the loop. Where are the i1,i2,etc values set? Rather than trying to post some partial code, can you instead post the *actual* code you're using in production? Otherwise, this question makes no sense.

Comment: @xjtan What is the range of the randomized data?

Comment: @KyleKanos. Thanks for your advice.  I was thinking to cut off the irrelevant information previously. Now the code is posted .

Comment: @curiousguy. They are integers and be large or small.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reduce the number of operations is to sort one of the arrays. But 4 elements is hardly worth it.

Perhaps when adding the numbers to the array then add them in a sorted order, otherwise quicksort is good for arrays under 10 elements in size.

Performing a binary search on a sorted array would give you O(log n) time for each search - with O(n log n) time to compare two full arrays of the same size. Quicksort is O(n log n), with binary search that's roughly O(2[n log n]).

Adding items in a sorted order, then searching, would be a similar complexity: O(n log n) for adding 'n' items, and O(n log n) for searching through n items. I prefer this solution because it's one simple algorithm, and it's cleaner.

Comment: I think for this  problem of small size(  by small I mean the size of the list is just four),  the complexity theory is not very useful here since I am only concern with this particular small system, the thing really matters here is cutting the number of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Though I think the problem here is not speed, but number of code lines.
For short code arrays would be best.

As extra in pseudo-code short (readable) code (with arrays):

```
// Determine equality between i[] and j[].
dim k(1 to 4)     // Indices into j[].
for m = 1 to 4
    k[m] = m
for m = 1 to 4
    found = false
    for n = m to 4
        if (i[m] == j[k[n]])
            found = true
            t = k[m]
            k[m] = k[n]
            break
    next n
    if !found fail
next m
```

One can roll this out using variables:

```
// (First version.)
// Determine equality between {i1, i2, i3, i4}] and {j1, j2, j3, j4}.
if i1 != j1
    if i1 != j2
        if i1 != j3
            if i1 != j4
                cycle
            else
                j4 = j1
        else
            j3 = j1
    else
        j2 = j1
if i2 != j2
    if i2 != j3
        if i2 != j4
            cycle
        else
            j4 = j2
    else
        j3 = j2
if i3 != j3
    if i3 != j4
        cycle
    else
        j4 = j3
if i4 != j4
    cycle
success
```

Which is the same as:

```
// (Second version.)
// Determine equality between {i1, i2, i3, i4}] and {j1, j2, j3, j4}.
if i1 == j4
    j4 = j1
else if i1 == j3
    j3 = j1
else if i1 == j2
    j2 = j1
else if i1 != j1

if i2 = j4
    j4 = j2
else if i2 = j3
    j3 = j2
eise if i2 != j2
    cycle

if i3 = j4
    j4 = j3
else if i3 != j3
    cycle

if i4 != j4
    cycle
```

Checking for no duplicates should be done first, and can be for instance:

```
if ((i1-i2)*(i1-i3)*(i1-i4)*(i2-i3)*(i2-i4) == 0) cycle
```

(Disregarding overflow of multiplication to 0!)

***As code review***

The array code version I gave, as that is reminiscant to your use of q1, q2, q3, q4: a kind of indexing. I would use **primes** in order to prevent a mix-up with `1*4=4` and `2*2=4`. (Or OR-ing of bit masks.)

For the rest the code has more the feel of assembly language (my code included).

The main optimisation would be in the *prelude* to this phase in coding: keeping a *set*, a sorted unique array.